# text as background. need 2nd background, need expert

Tags: javascript, html, css

My text is like background (body image) using

```
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color:transparent;
```

I would like to add moving element like on example below, but as you see if text color is set to yellow, everything is visible, but  when text is set same as background image you wont see output.

Here is my HTML

```
#myContainer {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
  background: yellow;
}
#myAnimation {
  width: 50px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
}
#animate{
position:relative;
text-align:center;
-webkit-background-clip: text;
        -webkit-text-fill-color:transparent;
        z-index:20;}

        #normal{
        position:relative;
        color:yellow;
        z-index:22;
        text-align:center;}


<p>
<button onclick="myMove()">Click Me</button> 
</p>

<div id ="myContainer">
<div id ="myAnimation"></div>
<p id="animate">some text with background color</p>
<p id="normal">some text with yellow color</p>
</div>
```

My Javascript

```
<script>
function myMove() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("myAnimation");   
  var pos = 0;
  var id = setInterval(frame, 10);
  var len = 50;
  var hei = 100;
  function frame() {
    if (pos == 80 && len <250) {
      pos=80;
      len++;

      elem.style.width = len + "px";

    } 
    else if (len >249) {
    hei--;

      elem.style.height = hei + "px";
    }

    else {
      pos++; 
      elem.style.left = pos + 'px'; 
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

In example I have set the background color as yellow and box as red. in My main project i have full HD img and around 50 shapes to create animated text. Main problem is that when box(shape) cover text with id #animate the text taking box background when it should stay with main body background(img)

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to accomplish :-( You want the first text to be yellow when the red box passes behind it?

Comment: I would like that: the 1st text with id #animate react same with red block as 2nd text with id #normal. that code is only a example. In my main project i have full hd image...

Comment: Answer below worked for me in Chrome

Comment: Can you create a working snippet and a demo on jsfiddle or codepen. It will help us with your problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

job done xD example  [pmwebdev.co.uk](http://%20pmwebdev.co.uk)

code for background:

```
body{
    background-image: url("bg.png");
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

code for text:

```
#slide1text{

    text-decoration-style: bold;
    margin: 0px;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    background-image: url("bg.png");
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color:transparent;
    color: red;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 20;
}
```